# Talk to a uwsgi RPC app from a non uwsgi process

Tags: python, rpc, uwsgi

We have a working uwsgi server with some RPC calls (Note: we're able to use uwsgi.rpc to talk to the processes, so the setup on their end is good).  We discovered that we have some processes that are not running under uwsgi that we want to talk to the RPC servers.  Looking at the uwsgi source, it looks like it should be relatively easy to communicate from a python process not running behind uwsgi, but all we're able to get is:

```
read(): Resource temporarily unavailable [proto/uwsgi.c line 75]
Fri Apr 12 15:21:07 2013 - error parsing request
```

Here is the code we're using.  I think it packages up the data correctly, but I'm not sure why it's not working:

```
import socket
from struct import pack

c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3035))

fun = 'test_fun'
arg = 'hi'
ulen = len(fun)
arglen = len(arg)
buflen = (2 + ulen) + (2 + arglen)
buf = pack('!B', 173)
buf += pack('!H', buflen)
buf += pack('!B', 0)
buf += pack('!B', ulen & 0xff)
buf += pack('!B', (ulen>>8) & 0xff)
buf += fun
buf += pack('!B', arglen & 0xff)
buf += pack('!B', (arglen>>8) & 0xff)
buf += arg

sent = c.send(buf)
c.close()
```

Comment: Any reason you're not just using the uwsgi library? http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RPC

Comment: We're using consumers everywhere.  It looks like we could use uwsgi, but we'd have to add some plugins (https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/29) and the only thing we need uwsgi for is to send RPC requests, so it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the header over separately from the body, and the length of your function + argument needs to be little endian.

```
fun = 'test_fun'                                                     
arg = 'hi'                                                                          
ulen = len(fun)                                                                    
arglen = len(arg)                                                                  
buflen = (2 + ulen) + (2 + arglen)                                                 
buf = pack('!B', 173)                                                              
buf += pack('<H', buflen)                                                          
buf += pack('!B', 0)                                                               
c.send(buf)                                     

buf = pack('!B', ulen & 0xff)                                                      
buf += pack('!B', (ulen>>8) & 0xff)                                                
buf += fun                                                                         
buf += pack('!B', arglen & 0xff)                                                   
buf += pack('!B', (arglen>>8) & 0xff)                                              
buf += arg                                                                         
sent = c.send(buf)                                                                 
print "sent", sent
```